# Understanding a French poem: 'Les 'aisselles' [...] Deviennent nucléaires'

Tags: sens, poésie

I am trying to understand what a part of a French poem, entitled 'Le pouvoir de ma mère', means. The poem is about the writer's mother who is Algerian and speaks the French language in a non-standard way. In the preceding section of the poem, she is talking about how she mispronounces certain French words like 'allocations familiales'. Then she goes on to say this:
‘Les ‘aisselles’ toutes simples/
Toutes familières et physiques celles-là/
Deviennent nucléaires/
À l’orée d’un reportage télévisé fatalement incompris.’
I have no idea what this could mean. What is the mother supposed to have misunderstood?

Answer (score 8):

I guess she misunderstood *essais nucléaires* and came up with *aisselles nucléaires* instead. France did a series of nuclear tests in Algeria in the 1960s.

Comment: Thank you. That seems like a sensible solution.

Comment: The correct interpretation, without any doubt.